# Can a SERIAL foreign key be set to null?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

**Question:** I have a table with a couple of foreign keys. I want to make two of the foreign keys optional (that is, they can be set to NULL). When I try to run the command to create the table, I get the error:

> ERROR:  conflicting NULL/NOT NULL declarations for column "activityid" of table "eventassociation"

If I try and create the table without the NULL declaration for the foreign keys, those foreign keys implicitly become NOT NULL.

How can I make it so that the foreign keys `activityID` and `roleID` can be null?

Thanks,

hypoz

**Extra information**:

I am running postgreSQL (version on apt-get) on ubuntu 12.04.

This is the problematic table:

```
CREATE TABLE eventAssociation (
  associationID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  studentID VARCHAR(12) references volunteers(studentID),
  eventID SERIAL references events(eventID),
  activityID SERIAL references activities NULL,
  roleID SERIAL references roles(roleID) NULL,
  coordinatorConfirmed BOOLEAN,
  userRevokeable BOOLEAN
)
```

And for reference, here is the schema for the `activities` table. The roles table is pretty much identical except with different field names.

```
CREATE TABLE activities (
  activityID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  eventID integer references events(eventID),
  name varchar(128),
  description TEXT
)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Defining a column that is a FK as `serial` does not make any sense. It means that whenever you don't supply a value, a new id will be **generated** - I cannot imagine any situation where that makes sens.

I think you actually want to define those columns as `integer`:

```
CREATE TABLE activities 
(
  activityID    SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  eventID       INTEGER REFERENCES events,
  name          VARCHAR(128),
  description   TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE eventAssociation 
(
  associationID          SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  eventID                INTEGER REFERENCES events,
  activityID             INTEGER REFERENCES activities,
  coordinatorConfirmed   BOOLEAN,
  userRevokeable         BOOLEAN
);
```

Comment: Ah, I was under the impression that `SERIAL` was a synonym for `integer`. I take it I am wrong and serial actually means integer with a sequence?

Comment: @64bit_twitchyliquid You can read details about `SERIAL` here : http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html